# Difference of “da” and “weil”

Tags: word-choice, difference, dialect

> Da ich nichts zu tun habe, gehe ich ins Fitnessstudio.
>
> Weil ich nichts zu tun habe, gehe ich ins Fitness.

Which one is more commonly used? *Da* or *weil?* And which one is dialectal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sentence with *weil* is definitely more commonly used in the spoken language. It has not much to do with dialect; I would say both versions are fine throughout Germany. One point is that when we speak, we often say it the other way around

> Ich gehe ins Fitnessstudio, weil ich nichts zu tun habe.

If you want to sound really *native-wrong* German, then you have to ignore the rule of putting the verb at the end in the relative clause. Therefore, on the street you would probably hear

> Ich war gestern im Fitnessstudio, weil ich hatte echt einfach nichts zu tun.

Comment: Das sagen meine Freunde die ganze Zeit u. es bringt mich mannchmal durcheinender, zumal ich kein Muttersprachler bin.

Comment: Das mit dem Verb bei "weil" ist wie eine Krankheit, die sich ausbreitet, aber wie sagt man so schoen.. Die Sprache lebt :-( Ach so, es heisst *manchmal* mit einem *n*.

Comment: @halirutan... ja, das ist wohl wahr. Ich glaube, dass ich mittlerweile im täglichen Gebrauch NIE das Verb ans Ende mache. Ich muss mich dafür richtig gehend konzentrieren. Aber vielleicht ist das auch nur eine Mode und verschwindet in ein paar Jahren wieder. Wer weiß das schon im voraus.

Answer (score 8):

The [*Atlas der deutschen Alltagssprache*](http://atlas-alltagssprache.de) did a survey covering that question, too.

In the example sentence

> … er jetzt doch nicht mitmacht, sind wir morgen nur sieben.

the colours in the following map represents where people would use *da, weil, nachdem, wo* or *wenn* (however, *wenn* would change the meaning at least as perceived by standard German speakers).

[image: weil er jetzt doch nicht mitmacht]

Clearly, it is more common to say *da* in the North, but *weil* dominates throughout. The second example sentence used was

> … die Renovierung noch länger dauern wird, können wir erst nächsten Monat einziehen.

*Weil* is still most common across the entire German dialect continuum, and *da* is still strong in the North. The South (not including Switzerland) often also allows the additional *nachdem,* although that *actually* signifies a temporal relationship.

[image: weil die Renovierung laenger dauert.]

The authors state that this is simply because causal relationships originally developped from temporal ones. Even Luther originally used the odd *nachdem* to signify causality; however, that usage was not really transferred into modern German. The full interpretation can be read [on the corresponding site of the *Atlas*](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/f3_12b.jpg)